# Trying to print page shows weird layout

Tags: python, css, html, pyramid

I want to be able to print my web page but when I choose print from right clicking or from the menu, the layout becomes nearly unreadable and ugly. Also there seems to be a red square somehow in the layout when trying to print( It's not there any more but left this sentence in here in case someone has dealt with it before). Is this due to the colours I have or something else?
Here is an example:
[image: the messed up layout]
and here is an example of what the page looks like normally:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) in your CSS to add styles that will only be used if the webpage is being printed. In your case, I would use such styles to:

1. Change the grey background to white
2. Add black outlines and white backgrounds to your textboxes
3. Change the text color to solid black
4. Adjust fonts to compensate for the printed page

Media queries are normally used to change a website for smaller screens, but they're also perfectly applicable for changing it for print. You can read more about using media queries specifically for print [here](http://www.creativebloq.com/responsive-web-design/make-your-website-printable-css-3132929).

Comment: That's the approach I started taking after I posted this question. Thanks for confirming my idea lol.